# Deneb line chart in combo bar-line chart is not continuous and appears to be mixing up data points

Tags: deneb

I'm a fairly new user to Deneb and Vega-Lite. I'm in the process of creating a bar-line combo chart that has a frequency as the line and counts as the stacked bar. I was able to create stacked bars. When I create the new line mark in the layer, the data points used for the line appear to be mixed up with the data points for the bar and the line (this is just what it looks like. this may not be what is happening). The line itself is not continuous.

Here is what I'm expecting to see:

[image: Chart that I'm expecting to see]

Here's what I get using the latest version of Deneb:

[image: Deneb attempt]

The pbix can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2m4jib5sor7lvafyf26p3/Test_Data.pbix?rlkey=ycxcrw21ec5mxslinwda0idzf&dl=0

I thought initially it was because I didn't have a Resolve step in my code but adding that in didn't solve the issue that I'm experiencing.

Anyone able to help?